# MySQL: COUNT() from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables `user`, `person` and `company`.
the `user_id` is a `foreign key` in both `person` and `company` tables.
what I want to do is to count how many persons and companies are related to each user, so I did the following query:

```
select u.id , u.username, count(c.user_id) as count_company, count(p.user_id) as count_people
from user u left join company c on (u.id = c.user_id)
left join person p on (u.id = p.user_id)
group by u.id, u.username
```

but I'm getting wrong result!!
This is the result I get:
[image]

however, when I try to count only the companies related to each user using this query:

```
select u.id , u.username, count(c.staff_user_id) as count_company
from fos_user u left join company c on (u.id = c.staff_user_id)
group by u.id, u.username
```

I get this result:
[image]

what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a user is related to multiple companies and/or multiple persons, then you always count the *cross join* of them - Which is then the number of companies multiplied with the number of persons.

To solve that problem (in your case) I would just use subqueries:

```
select u.id, u.username, 
    (select count(*) from company c where u.id = c.user_id) as count_company,
    (select count(*) from person p  where u.id = p.user_id) as count_people
from user u
```

Note that a double join like in your query is from relational point of view (in most cases) just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

seems you need the distinct count

```
select u.id 
    , u.username
    , count(distinct c.user_id) as count_company
    , count(distinct p.user_id) as count_people
from user u 
left join company c on (u.id = c.user_id)
left join person p on (u.id = p.user_id)
group by u.id, u.username
```

count(col)    count the not null values for col in relation  ... count(distinct col)  count the distinct value for col1